# Virgin Atlantic Upgrade to Upper Class at Check-in - no seats open in seat map

Tags: upgrades, virgin-atlantic

I am interested in upgrading to upper class on my flight from LAX-LHR on Virgin Atlantic. I can see on forums online and on Virgin's website that they allow purchasing upgrades at check-in.

I am looking at the seat availability on my flight and it looks like no seats are open in Upper Class. Is it likely that Virgin will release more seats during check-in?

Comment: Is Upper Class still available for purchase on the Virgin Atlantic site for that specific flight?  If not, then it’s highly likely the flight is sold out in that class.

Comment: How did you check seat availability? You might not see Upper Class seats in "my booking". As Moo said, if they still sell tickets there is seats left so go through the booking flow to see seat availability, but note that there might be passengers that haven't selected a seat.